# Connect Jack with Web audio context

Tags: web-audio-api, jack

Is it possible to interconnect the `Web Audio context` with the `Jack audio connection kit`?

My browser doesn't appear in QjackCtl, only the system sound is available. So I can't connect my audio web app as an audio element, for example a sound effect.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it would depend on the browser. Firefox had a jack audio back-end at some point, maybe it could be resurrected ?

Comment: Good to know. Thanks.