# How to choose a specific audio output device in Firefox or Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, audio, browser, asio

I'm building a low-latency sampler in the browser (using Javascript, WASM, etc.).

How to choose, from Javascript, a specific audio output device for Chrome or Firefox?

I see there is [Audio Output API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/selectAudioOutput) but there are not many examples (and by the way `navigator.mediaDevices.selectAudioOutput` is undefined on my Chrome 109).

For example, how to make Chrome use Asio4All as main output device?

(Note: using an ASIO device such as the free Asio4All driver can make the latency drop from 30 milliseconds to 5 milliseconds, even on an old computer).

Comment: It remember me a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31765358/5156280) I post some time ago...

Answer (score 1):

There is also Audio Output Devices API which can be used to achieved the similar functionality.

```js
// First Create a new audio element
    var audio = new Audio("https://samplelib.com/lib/preview/mp3/sample-3s.mp3");
    
    // Get the list of available audio output devices
    navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
      .then(function(devices) {
        // Filter the devices to get only the audio output ones
        var audioOutputDevices = devices.filter(function(device) {
          return device.kind === "audiooutput";
        });
        // Log the devices to the console
        console.log(audioOutputDevices);
        // If there is at least one audio output device, use the first one as the output device
        if (audioOutputDevices.length > 0) {
          // Set the sink ID of the audio element to the device ID of the first audio output device
          audio.setSinkId(audioOutputDevices[0].deviceId)
            .then(function() {
              // Play the audio
              audio.play();
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
              // Handle any errors
              console.error(error);
            });
        }
      })
```

The `audioOutputDevices[]` can be leveraged to choose between vaious output devices.

Comment: Do you get various devices on this list? I don't see low-latency devices like ASIO4ALL (https://www.asio4all.org/), I only see 1 device. BTW for future readers it would be great to edit your answer to convert it into a runnable snippet.

Comment: sure i will do that. Unfortunately i am unable  to get ASIO4ALL working on my Windows 11 machine

Comment: Thanks @AvinashChandravansi. How many devices do you see in this list on your Windows 11 computer? I would be interested in knowing how many devices you see and if there are multiple variations for the same device, based on the audio backend: DirectX, WASAPI, etc.

Comment: Myself, I only see `[{
    "deviceId": "",
    "kind": "audiooutput",
    "label": "",
    "groupId": "bbb59..."
  }]` on my Windows laptop.

Comment: I am able to see only one audio output device in my system setting as well

Comment: [Permissions are gated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices) by the [Permission API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions_API). Also, enumerateDevices() must be used in a [secure context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts).